# TFS: locked files are still read only for external editors

Tags: tfs, locking, edit

We use TFS in server workspace mode. I locked some directory and files inside are editable for me in Visual Studio but still in read only mode in my external editors (notepad, pspad, ...).

How can i lock the directory to have all files writable "outside" the Visual Studio?

I found out that one option is to lock directory by "Checkout for Edit" but after that I will see all files in "Pending Changes" even no file was changed.

Answer (score 2):

Check out for edit is the way to go. And the only way to go.

You can then later can Undo Unchanged from the [TFS Power tools or the TFS Source Control Extnsions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22152342/736079).